# Using textscan to read certain rows

Tags: matlab, textscan

I am trying to read data from a text file using `textscan` from Matlab. Currently, the code is provided below reads rows 1 to 4. I need it to read rows from 5 to 8, then rows from 9 to 13 and so on. How would I achieve this?

```
fileID=fopen(fileName);
num_rows=4;
nHeaderLines = 2; 
formatSpec = '%*s %*s %s %s %*s %*s %*s %f %*s';
dataIn = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,num_rows,'HeaderLines',nHeaderLines, 'Delimiter',',' );
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: Can you give example of the content of your files, as well as formatSpec and nHeaderLines?

Comment: Content of File
Identification                          TEMP     
GGSA   ABCD  Date     HrMn I Type  QCP  Temp   Q 
829039,10000,20350311,0053,7,FM-15,    ,  62.0,5,
382919,10000,20350311,0153,7,FM-15,    ,  65.4,5,
030291,10000,20350311,0253,7,FM-15,    ,  68.4,5,
goes on for 300+ rows.....

nHeaderLines = 2;
formatSpec = '%*s %*s %s %s %*s %*s %*s %f %*s';

Comment: If the file is not too large then,you can read the whole file and then go through the obtained cell or matrix to get specified rows.

Comment: I assume you have a typo? (5-8 is 4 rows, while 9-13 is 5 rows)

Comment: Like Nishant said just read the entire file. It seems that you are doing that any way. 1:4,5:8,9:12,...,end-3:end

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
file = fopen('myfile');             
content = textscan(file,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(file);
```

and you have all the lines in your file as cell array of strings. Then take any number of rows you want and process them as you like.